# Nginx redirect on folder request but allow subfolders of that folder to pass

Tags: linux, nginx, 301-redirect

I have the following Nginx config which i want it to apply 2 rules.

## Rule 1

When the URL request contains the subdirectory /shop to be 301 redirected to the frontpage of the website. For example: https://mywebsite.com/shop to become https://mywebsite.com

```
location /shop {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ https://v2.no7.de redirect;
}
```

## Rule2

When the URL request contains the subdirectory with an extra subdirectory or file then dont rewrite anything.  For example: https://mywebsite.com/shop/subcategory/product

```
location / {
  if ($request_uri ~ "^/shop/(.*)$"){
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://v2.no7.de/%1 redirect;
  }
}
```

But when im importing this configuration on the ISPConfig panel i get an error that this code is not right and no other explanation given.

Could someone help me figure out this one?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I am not familiar with the "ISPConfig panel", but you should probably be using: `location = /shop { return 301 /; }` which will satisfy both rules in your question.

Comment: Yes the '=' designates an exact match. more -> http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: Hi @RichardSmith,
I used it the way you say including a “=“ but still gets rejected by the ISPConfig. 
Is it possible what im trying to actually? Thanks for your time!